# pandas sum rows base on multiple groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe

```
df1

name         triggerid description                      time                            
srvjboss03   30708     Access URL A failed              01:19:23
srvjboss03   30708     Access URL A failed              01:18:21
srvglass01   32942     Service Glassfish OFFLINE        00:35:00
srvglass01   32942     Service Glassfish OFFLINE        00:35:00
srvglass01   22725     Access URL B failed              00:36:04
srvglass01   22725     Access URL B failed              00:36:07
srvglass01   22725     Access URL B failed              00:06:04
srvglass01   22725     Access URL B failed              00:06:04
```

The desire output is:

```
name         triggerid description                      time                            
srvjboss03   30708     Access URL A failed              02:31:44
srvglass01   32942     Service Glassfish OFFLINE        01:10:00
srvglass01   22725     Access URL B failed              01:24:21
```

Time is the sum o times in rows  that have the same name, triggerid and description.

I tried to set the columns name, triggerid and description as index and then agroup but I get this.

```
df1.set_index(['name', 'triggerid', 'descrption'], inplace=True)

df1.groupby(df.index)['time'].sum()


name         triggerid description                      time
srvjboss03   30708     Access URL A failed              01:19:23
                       Access URL A failed              01:18:21
srvglass01   32942     Service Glassfish OFFLINE        00:35:00
                       Service Glassfish OFFLINE        00:35:00
srvglass01   22725     Access URL B failed              00:36:04
                       Access URL B failed              00:36:07
                       Access URL B failed              00:06:04
                       Access URL B failed              00:06:04
```

The columns time is set as timedelta64. 
Why pandas do not group description the same way name and triggerid?
How can I get the desired output?

Comment: its dose not make sense , sum time like this ...

Comment: @Wen Why not? I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try this.  First convert time column to timedelta.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])

df.groupby(['name','triggerid','description'])['time'].sum()\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         name  triggerid                description     time
0  srvglass01      22725        Access URL B failed 01:24:19
1  srvglass01      32942  Service Glassfish OFFLINE 01:10:00
2  srvjboss03      30708        Access URL A failed 02:37:44
```

*Other alternatives:*

```
df2 = df.set_index(['name','triggerid','description'])
df2.groupby(df2.index)['time'].sum()
```

output:

```
(srvglass01, 22725, Access URL B failed)         01:24:19
(srvglass01, 32942, Service Glassfish OFFLINE)   01:10:00
(srvjboss03, 30708, Access URL A failed)         02:37:44
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Or

```
df2.groupby(level=[0,1,2])['time'].sum()
```

Output:

```
name        triggerid  description              
srvglass01  22725      Access URL B failed         01:24:19
            32942      Service Glassfish OFFLINE   01:10:00
srvjboss03  30708      Access URL A failed         02:37:44
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Late by 30 secs:( +1

Comment: @Vaishali :)  Next time.   No pun intended.

Comment: time is already timedelta, df.groupby(['name','triggerid','description'])['time'].sum() is the same as df.groupby(df.index)['time'].sum()

Comment: @Vaishaili you get another chance ;-)

Comment: Are those first three columns in your index?  Then, yes.

Comment: df1.set_index(['name', 'triggerid', 'descrption'], inplace=True)

Comment: What is your issue, I ran your data and that is the output I am getting?  Are you getting something different?

Comment: @ScottBoston My code is right and also your answer. There was a **df1.reset_index..** between df1.groupby(df.index)['time'].sum() and the print. Thanks anyway

Comment: @JoaoVitorino Great, I am glad you figured it out!  Happy coding!